# Run an init function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have my codeigniter setup in which I have a whole bunch of autoloaded helpers, libraries etc. I have a function written which I want to execute before the application bootstraps. Lets call the function `init()` and assume its defined in one of the helpers. Problem is that it uses functions from other autoloaded helpers and libraries etc so calling the init() in the autoloaded file itself does not help because it runs into 'call to undefined function X' etc..

So I want to make the init() call after everything has loaded..I cannot call it in the default controller, because users might have a different URL bookmarked.

What is the best way to call init() in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [hook](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html) in `application/config/hooks.php`

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = function()
{
    // ...
};
```

You may use a function declared in another file, for example:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    // ...
    'function' => 'init'
);
```

There are many hooks available but in your case, the 'pre_controller' hook seems appropriate to me because `pre_controller` called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes, routing, and security checks have been done.